# If...Then...Else with multiple statements after Then

Tags: vba, if-statement, conditional-statements

a very easy question: considering an `If...Then...Else` instruction in VBA, how can I separate multiple instructions after `Then`? In other words, should I write something like

```
If condition [ Then ]    
   [ statement1 ] & [statement2] 
Else [Else statement] (i.e. using "&"),
```

or

```
If condition [ Then ]         
   [ statement1 ] And [statement2] 
Else [Else statement] (i.e. using "And"),
```

or some other separator/command?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing. & is a concatenator for strings `"a" & "b"`; And is logical `If a And b then` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Multiple statements are to be separated by a new line:

```
If SkyIsBlue Then
  StartEngines
  Pollute
ElseIf SkyIsRed Then
  StopAttack
  Vent
ElseIf SkyIsYellow Then
  If Sunset Then
    Sleep
  ElseIf Sunrise or IsMorning Then
    Smoke
    GetCoffee
  Else
    Error
  End If
Else
  Joke
  Laugh
End If
```

Comment: I do not why, but it reminds me of Warhammer 40K :-) Thanks again!

Comment: Or you can separate them with : eg. `StoppAttack : Vent`

Answer (score 1):

This works with multiple statements:

```
if condition1 Then stmt1:stmt2 Else if condition2 Then stmt3:stmt4 Else stmt5:stmt6
```

Or you can split it over multiple lines:

```
if condition1 Then stmt1:stmt2
Else if condition2 Then stmt3:stmt4
Else stmt5:stmt6
```