# Multiple Worksheet Change Formulas - multiple actions for when certain criteria are selected on a drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create multiple actions for when certain criteria are selected on a drop down list. I have 6 entries in the drop down list and 3 of which need automated actions.

First action is..

When "4. Under Offer" is selected, an inputbox should popup requesting a "date" value to be inputted ("Please insert a date the property went under offer"). This value will likely be a date but sometimes will be just text. The value needs to then be inputted to the cell immediately to the right of cell with the "4. Under Offer" dropdown value.

Second action is...

When "5. Exchanged" is selected, an inputbox should popup requesting a "date" value to be inputted ("Please insert a date the property Exchanged"). This value will likely be a date but sometimes will be just text. The value needs to then be inputted to the cell 28 cells to the right of cell with the "5. Exchanged" dropdown value.

The third action is...

When "6. Completed" is selected,an inputbox should popup requesting a "Purchase Price" and "Purchaser" value to be inputted ("Please insert a purchase price and a Purchaser"). The purchase price value will be a £ number and will need to be inputted into a cell 23 cells to the right of the cell with the "6. Completed" dropdown value. The purchaser value will be a text value and will need to be inputted into a cell 22 cells to the right of the cell with the "6. Completed" dropdown value. The whole row is then copied and pasted under the last row of text in a sheet called "Deals Schedule". Then the row is then deleted from the source sheet (called Disposals).

I have started to create the code but I am lost because there is only so much I can piece together from online forums. I have very limited understanding of VBA.

Really appreciate any help.

I have had some success with the actions individually but not as one.

The code I have tried is below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim A As Range
Dim P As String
Set A = Range("B2:B9999")
If Intersect(Target, A) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value = "4. Under Offer" Then
P = InputBox("please enter date")
ActiveCell.Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = P

Else

If Target.Value = "5. Exchanged" Then
P = InputBox("please enter date")
ActiveCell.Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 28).Activate
ActiveCell.Value = P


Dim LR As Long
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Else

If Target.Value = "6. Completed" Then

        P = InputBox("please enter a purchase price")
        ActiveCell.Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 23).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = P

        P = InputBox("please enter purchaser")
        ActiveCell.Activate
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 22).Activate
        ActiveCell.Value = P

         varResponse = MsgBox("Please confirm the status is 'complete'! Have you put in pricing information and purchaser? The data will be moved to the 'Deal Schedule' tab in red below..... Press 'Yes' To Proceed or 'No' To Cancel", vbYesNo, "Selection")
        If varResponse <> vbYes Then Exit Sub
        LR = Sheets("Deals Schedule").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Target.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheets("Deals Schedule").Range("A" & LR).PasteSpecial
        Flag = True
        Target.EntireRow.Delete
        End If

            End If


Application.CutCopyMode = False
Flag = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Please tell us what is not working about the code you posted.

Comment: You should look more into VBA's If-ElseIf-Else statements. Some resources: [brief sample code with proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15459974/9259306), [web blog with explanations and examples](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-if/), [sample code with multiple elseif statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42233161/9259306)

Comment: Also, simply combining each `Else` and next `If` statements will result in the `LR` variable only getting assigned a value if the `Target.Value` equals 5, while it's used when `Target.Value = 6`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 Application.EnableEvents = False  'must stop reacting or we will get into a loop when we delete target below

Dim P As String

If Target.Column <> 2 Then 'only column B
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
End If
Select Case Target.Text
    Case Is = "4. Under Offer"
        P = InputBox("please enter date")
        Target.Offset(0, 1) = P

   Case Is = "5. Exchanged"
        P = InputBox("please enter date")
        Target.Offset(0, 28) = P

    Case Is = "6. Completed"

        P = InputBox("please enter a purchase price")
        Target.Offset(0, 23) = P

        P = InputBox("please enter purchaser")

        Target.Offset(0, 22) = P
        Dim varResponse
         varResponse = MsgBox("Please confirm the status is 'complete'! Have you put in pricing information and purchaser? The data will be moved to the 'Deal Schedule' tab in red below..... Press 'Yes' To Proceed or 'No' To Cancel", vbYesNo, "Selection")
        If varResponse = vbYes Then
            Dim LR As Long
            LR = Sheets("Deals Schedule").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            Target.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Deals Schedule").Range("A" & LR)
            Target.EntireRow.Delete
        End If
End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True 'must turn the react back on


End Sub
```